# Can not add Crystal Report in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, report, reporting

Anyone know why I can not add Crystal Report in visual studio 2017 Community,
although I already install the Crystal Report, but it still can not be found, and reporting menu was lost in Add New Item

Answer (score 0):

Check the target framework of the project you created. By default a new WinForms project gets set to *.NET Framework 4 Client Profile*. To fix your problem change it to *.NET Framework 4.*

To do this right-click your project and select Properties. On the Application tab set the Target Framework dropdown.

or you can do this *right-click **project** and select **Properties**. On the Compile tab, Click **Advance Compile Options**... and set the Target Framework dropdown to .NET Framework version*